# How to iterate without duplication in php

Tags: php

I want to print custom_question without duplication and it custom_question_answer using loop in php 
link of the db is as given below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i joined two table and got the above result. but   for displaying i am having problem

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Helpful to you and get more clear idea about.

```
<?php
$arr = $arr_history = array("1stQuestion?","2ndQuestion?","3rdQuestion?","4thQuestion?");

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++ )
{
    if (empty($arr_history)){ $arr_history = $arr; }
    $key = array_rand($arr_history, 1);
    $selected = $arr_history[$key];
    unset($arr_history[$key]);
    echo $selected . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```